# How To Keep Data on a HDD Alive ((charged, healthy)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, storage

I'm aware that HDD write the data to disk by means of magnetic charges to a tiny spot on the platter(s) inside. I also discovered (by experience) that after a period of time, this data can get corrupted (probably because the magnetic charge isn't strong enough anymore). Now I am a collector. I hardly ever delete anything & I always want the stored to be accesible so I have nog an 10TB external HDD, but I fear that discharging might render my data unusable.

Is there a way I can prevent my HDD from "losing" data. And is that a reasonably easy way?

Comment: The data should be good for a couple of years. Beyond that is probably not advisable and hard drives are certainly not an offline permanent storage method. Keep old data on current computers and today, best with SSD drives.

Comment: "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary". One HD is not enough. You need one in-house, one off-site & one online to cover all your bases. Then you can consider copying to a fresh drive every so often with checksumming to test data-retention.

Comment: I use this utility on level 4 to read and re-write all data on the drive (partitions), not free though>>>>https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm

Comment: @Moab - **Spinrite is incompatible with any HDD larger then 2 TB.**  It's also incompatible with USB external HDDs.  Spinrite has not been updated in nearly a decade.

Comment: He is working on 6.1 right now.